# Can anyone identify the source of SCP-008-B?

Tags: story-identification, horror, scp-foundation

I came across a Youtube video called SCP-008-B "Crystal Plague". It's a reading of an SCP that is similar to but not exactly like the "Zombie Plague" SCP-008. Unlike the SCP-008 that people are more familiar with, 008-B is supposed to be a radioactive crystalline parasite. However, I do not know where the author of the video found the SCP entry or whether he/she has made it up. I do remember seeing this video a few years ago, and I may or may not have found the text entry used for it, though my memory is fuzzy. It's not on the SCP wiki.
Does anyone know where this alternative SCP is from, and, if so, could you provide a link?

The video in question:

Comment: Have you checked the discussion page on SCP-008 and/or the revision history? SCPs are sometimes updated and changed, so this might be an earlier telling/remembering

Comment: Unfortunately, the wiki got hacked around 2015, so a lot of history got lost.